# How to use npm mp3 to wav

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

When attempting to convert an **mp3** to **wav** using `npm mp3-to-wav`, the console returns,

> "mp3 to wav exec err: saveForWav err: Path must be a string. Received
>   [ 'C:\Projects\Weatherman\meme.wav' ]"

I'm fairly certain what I'm feeding it is a string, so I have not a clue where the problem lies.  `npm mp3-to-wav` can be found at https://www.npmjs.com/package/mp3-to-wav#2-usage and here's my code.

```
const Mp32Wav = require('mp3-to-wav');

new Mp32Wav("C:/Projects/Weatherman/meme.MP3").exec()
```

How do I get the file to receive the directory path and is there a problem with my directory path?

Comment: Most Windows paths use backslashes (`\\ `). I don’t know enough about the library to know if that’s the problem though.

Answer (score 0):

the err you get is not from 'mp3-to-wav' its from fs
there isnt any problem with your path

```
  class Mp32Wav {

      constructor(input_file_path, output_dir) {

        if (!utils.checkArgsNotNull(...input_file_path)) {
          throw new Error('err arguments')
        }
        output_dir = utils.judgeNotNull(output_dir) ? output_dir : utils.splitFileDir(input_file_path)
        this._input_file_path = input_file_path
        this._input_file_name = utils.splitFilename(input_file_path)
        this._output_dir = output_dir
        this._output_file_name = this._input_file_name.toString().replace(/\.mp3/i, '')
      }
```

as you can see in their constructor they ignore case sensitive

```
.replace(/\.mp3/i, '')
```

I don't use windows but I think it will be helpful for you to use path module to create your path and check if its absolute

**Node.js path.isAbsolute() Method**

https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/met_path_isabsolute.asp

**also, all examples in w3c use double \\ insted of \ in windows**

for example

```
console.log(path.isAbsolute('C:\\test\\demo_path.js')); //true
```